# URL Redirect Based on Screen Length or height

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, mobile

So how to i get that code with length screen, can anyone help me. I try this code on the header and it doesn't work:
"<script type=""text/javascript""> if (screen.length <= 1500) { window.location = ""https://www.google.com/""

I want a code can do it

Comment: Check `window.innerWidth` instead.

Comment: There is no such property like `screen.length`, see all the available properties in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen)

Comment: tks alot, do you know what exactly code i should use. Sorry i just an amateur, im a new digital marketer